# How can I let ESP32 communication with Google sheet

Tags: esp32

I use ESP32 board to communicate with Google sheet.
I can write data to Google sheet.
But I can not read the data from Google sheet.
Could you give me some suggestion? Thanks

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include "HTTPSRedirect.h"
const char* ssid = " ";
const char* password = " ";
const char* host = "script.google.com";
const char *GScriptId = "";
const int httpsPort = 443;
HTTPSRedirect* client ;
void setup(){
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  client = new HTTPSRedirect(httpsPort);
  client->setPrintResponseBody(true);
  client->setContentTypeHeader("application/json");
  client->connect(host, httpsPort);
}
void loop() {
  String url3 = String("/macros/s/") + GScriptId + "/exec?&id="; 
  Serial.println("GS1");      
  if (client->GET(url3, host)){
      Serial.println("GET SUCCESS");
  }  
  Serial.println("GS2");
  delay(4000);                          
}
```

when I run the code,the serial windows can see the message:GS1,But only one time. The serial windows would not show more information anymore.So I can not see the message:GET SUCCESS.I can not see the message:GS2.

Comment: It seems like there's an error on `client->GET(url3, host)` which stops further progress. Add a Serial.println(url3) to verify the url is correct. And add another Serial.println for the result of client->Get.... to see what actually happened

Comment: Thanks for your help, If I write data to google sheet,it;s ok. So I already verified the url was correctly.

Comment: The documentation of HTTPSRedirect mentions you can enable debug messages:

Sec. III(c) Debugging

HTTPSRedirect supports a debugging mode for developers. This prints out extra debugging information to the Serial output when enabled. To enable, uncomment this line within DebugMacros.h: #define DEBUG.

Answer (score 0):

When you can't debug, figure out how you can debug. I suppose you can have a serial connection to your ESP, and the ESP is able to send messages.

So what you can do is to add Serial.Write(variable) statements every now and then. Then when you're connected to the ESP you get a Serial response with the variable content. This way you can do some debugging. Maybe one of your strings is incorrect.

Comment: I modofied my question and thanks for your information.I can see the message:GS1 one time. The serial windows would not show more information anymore.So I can not see the message:GET SUCCESS.I can not see the message:GS2.